# Mount(Windows Drive) gets unmount whenever I reboot my system

Tags: 14.04

i use system with two OS i.e Windows 10 and UBUNTU 14.04...
I made sure that windows has fastboot ON and I am unable to solve this problem so help me out so that my windows drive does not get unmount after system reboot

Comment: Turn fast boot off

Answer (score 0):

If you want Ubuntu to automount a partition at startup, you must configure it to do that either by manually editing the `/etc/fstab` file (advanced method) or by using `gnome-disks`' GUI settings dialog (easy method). I'll describe the easy method here:

1. Open your Dash's Application lens (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and search for the application `gnome-disks` (or simply "Disks"). Launch it.
2. Select the disk where the partition you want to mount is located in the left side panel. In the right panel, select the partition you want to automount.
3. Click the gear button below ("Additional partition options") and select "Edit mount options..." from the appearing menu.
4. In the new dialog window, switch "Automatic mount options" off. Now the manual settings unlock.
5. You should make sure that "Mount at startup" and "Show in user interface" are checked. You can edit the "Display name" and "Icon name" if you want, but you should leave the mount options line (no caption) as it is. "Mount point" specifies the directory through which you want to access the partition. You should edit this field as well. The other options should remain as they are unless you know what to do.
6. Close the dialog by clicking "OK" and exit `gnome-disks`.

To be able to mount the Windows partition writeable, make sure that Windows Fast Boot is turned OFF though, otherwise Ubuntu can just mount the partition in read-only mode.